# Emacs-26 Big Sur (Intel) 11.2 - make fails error 137 macroexp.elc

Tags: osx, emacs26, source

Xcode: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815
CommandLineTools: 12.4.0.0.1.1610135815

I've exported CC=clang, but I can't get the emacs-26 branch to compile on my Big Sur Intel machine.

See gist [here](https://gist.github.com/thecocoa/b21942bd0bc86001f6f2f22a804310f6)

.autogen.sh and configure complete without errors.  The make is throwing the error.
FWIW, version 28 and version 27 compile and install without errors.

Comment: I completely understand that you want this to work.  I can tell you that it compiles and installs on OSX 10.6.8, but that doesn't help you....  I see that the last change to that branch was the latter part of 2019, which means that the chances of convincing the Emacs Devel to fix something on that branch is in the range of "slim to none".  I can point you to https://emacsformacosx.com/ and click on other-versions, but you are like me and want to build your own from source -- I get that.  A failed byte-compilation during `make` is *not* necessarily indicative of a bug in the `*.el` file.

Comment: @lawlist yeah, I'm aware of the alternative installation options.  I appreciate your reply.  I was just trying to figure out what I was missing (since emacsformacosx.com and others have success).  Definitely not expecting a fix from the devs, just trying to learn.  Thanks, again.